# Electric car charge depletion time?

Tags: batteries

I'm assuming these batteries are similar to or exactly like a capacitor? Also is there an equation to determine the charge decay rate based on usage and/or the time it stays still? If i wanted to make a model of this charge depletion so i can calculate how much time i need to wait for the car to charge based on material constants, could i use the RC circuit? If i can, where can i find those material constants?

If it is the RC circuit would this be correct?
$$
Q_0=CV_0
$$
$$
Q_{charged}(t)=Q_0(1-e^{-t/RC}), Q_{used}(t)=1-Q_{charged}(t), V_{used}(t)=\frac{Q_0}{C} e^{-t/RC}
$$

$$
I_{used}(t)=\frac{dQ_{used}}{dt}=\frac{Q_0}{RC}e^{-t/RC}
$$

$$
P_{used}(t)=I_{used}(t)V_{used}(t)=\frac{Q_0^2}{RC^2}e^{\frac{-2t}{RC}}
$$
$$
P_{drive}=I_{drive}V_{drive}, P_{total}(t)=P_{used}(t)-P_{drive}
$$

The reason i'm asking is because i've been looking at these electric cars, and though the mileage is amazing, i see that their charge depletes pretty fast and you have to charge them for a long time as well. Also, i don't know if this is true, but on some forums people have said that i guess they're usually paranoid about running out of charge so i'm assuming there's a power threshold since charge is proportional to voltage to where the car will just stop working, and that would be a primary concern for charging it so often.
Sorry this question has so many sub-questions, try to answer at least a few of them, i'm just curious about this.

Comment: Can refer to a specific electric car or type of electric car battery? Not all electric car batteries are the same.

Answer (score 2):

Car batteries (mostly lithium ion batteries) are not really like capacitors at all. Batteries store charge as chemical energy, whereas capacitors store energy in an electric field. Capacitor equations don't work at all for batteries.

Instead of us trying to answer this very broad question, I'd recommend doing a little reading. Here's two pages to start with. Battery voltage and state of charge are related, but not linearly. State of charge also varies depending upon how fast you discharge the batteries.

http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/lithium_based_batteries
http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/what_is_the_c_rate

Over time, I've found battery university does a good job of explaining most things batteries that I've been interested in. Once you get a basic understanding of the operations of how batteries work from there, if you still have questions, feel free to post another question that's more specific.

Comment: Thanks for those links. I can always look at graphs, but they have no formulas, therefore not answering this question at least partially and at least in a simplified formula.